# Random Array of Object Posts Running Twice on .map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, jsx

I'm creating a suggested events component. I want to render 4 randoms items from inside of an array of objects. It works for a split second, displaying 4 random items, but then it re-loads another 4 items, giving me 2 errors:

Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

Error: There was an error while hydrating this Suspense boundary. Switched to client rendering.

```
export function SuggestedEvents() {
  function getMultipleRandom(
    posts: {
      id: number
      title: string
      description: string
      image: string
      date: string
    }[],
    num: number | undefined
  ) {
    const shuffled = [...posts].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())

    return shuffled.slice(0, num)
  }

  return (
    <section className="py-6 lg:py-10">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4">
        {getMultipleRandom(posts, 4).map((item) => (
          <Link href={`/browse/${item.id}`} key={item.id}>
            <EventCard
              title={item.title}
              description={item.description}
              image={item.image}
              date={item.date}
              key={item.id}
            />
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

const posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "This is a really cool title btw",
    description:
      "This is a really cool title btw and everyone likes it a lot. This is a really cool title btw.",
    image: "/images/1.jpeg",
    date: "01/11/2023",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "This is a really cool title btw",
    description:
      "This is a really cool title btw and everyone likes it a lot btw and everyone likes it a lot",
    image: "/images/2.jpeg",
    date: "01/11/2023",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "This is a really cool title btw",
    description: "This is a really cool title btw and everyone likes it a lot",
    image: "/images/3.jpeg",
    date: "01/11/2023",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "This is a really cool title btw",
    description:
      "This is a really cool title btw and everyone likes it a lot btw and everyone likes it a lot",
    image: "/images/4.jpeg",
    date: "01/11/2023",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "This is a really cool title btw",
    description: "This is a really cool title btw and everyone likes it a lot",
    image: "/images/5.jpeg",
    date: "01/11/2023",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: "This is a really cool title btw",
    description: "This is a really cool title btw and everyone likes it a lot",
    image: "/images/6.jpeg",
    date: "01/11/2023",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    title: "This is a really cool title btw",
    description: "This is a really cool title btw and everyone likes it a lot",
    image: "/images/7.jpeg",
    date: "01/11/2023",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    title: "This is a really cool title btw",
    description: "This is a really cool title btw and everyone likes it a lot",
    image: "/images/8.jpeg",
    date: "01/11/2023",
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    title: "This is a really cool title btw",
    description: "This is a really cool title btw and everyone likes it a lot",
    image: "/images/9.jpeg",
    date: "01/11/2023",
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    title: "This is a really cool title btw",
    description: "This is a really cool title btw and everyone likes it a lot",
    image: "/images/10.jpeg",
    date: "01/11/2023",
  },
```

I think this comes from the .map running over all of my array items and not only with the 4 sliced items I want, but I'm unsure.

This mocked array at some point will come from an API of a lot of user posted content, so I would eventually grab a number of random posts from there.

Comment: Your test compares the results of 2 renderings, a client and a server side render, to make sure they are identical.  The list is being generated twice and it’s different because of random.  See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Comment: For what it's worth, that's not a good way to shuffle. Google "Fisher Yates shuffle" for more info and the standard way to shuffle a list.